# Имитация всех действий при загрузке файлов в e2e тестах protractor, как?

Tags: angular2, protractor

Здравствуйте!
Провожу e2e тестирование сайта с использованием protractor. 
Нужно полностью сымитировать действия пользователя при загрузке файла на сайт. 
Алгоритм такой:

1. Происходит открытие страницы
2. Нажимается кнопка "Загрузить"
3. Появляется стандартное окно с выбором файлов для загрузки
4. Выбирается файл
5. Файл загружается на сервер

Проблема и не понимание появляются на 3 шаге. Не понимаю, как можно сымитировать движение мыши в окне выбора файлов и сделать двойной клик по файлу, чтобы он загрузился. Как рассчитать координаты мыши, где она должна сделать двойной клик и вообще возможно ли это? 
Подскажите, пожалуйста. Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с этим.

Comment: Непосредственно открытие диалогового окна и работа с ним - работа браузера/ос, которую нет смысла тестировать. Вы можете просто напрямую в input указать путь к файлу. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21305298/2908793 https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#user-content-q-does-webdriver-support-file-uploads

Comment: @etki Пробовал делать таким образом, выдает ошибку: Failed: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Chunk size is 0}